# Orthogonal matrix $O$ maximising $Tr(OM)$.

Tags: optimization, trace, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

One can prove that the set $\{ Tr(OM) /$  $O$  $\in$ $ O_n ( \mathbb R ) $  $\}$ has a maximum for a certain orthogonal matrix $O$, furthermore, the application $f$ : $M_n (\mathbb R)$ $\mapsto$ $\mathbb R$
such as that $f(M) = max(  \{ Tr(OM) /$  $O$  $\in$ $ O_n ( \mathbb R ) $  $\}$ is continuous.
And for all $M \in S_n ^{+}(\mathbb R)$, $f(M) = Tr(M) $
So in order to prove that for $O\in$ $ O_n ( \mathbb R ) $ :   $f(M) =Tr( OM)$   **iff**   $OM \in S_n ^{+}(\mathbb R)$, one can prove that $f(M) = Tr(M)$ **iff** $M \in S_n ^{+}(\mathbb R)$.
I tried to prove that if $f(M) = Tr(M)$ then at least $M$ is symmetric, which should obviously be the fist step but to no avail.
Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe [von Neumann's trace inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequality#Von_Neumann's_trace_inequality_and_related_results) can be useful here? All you have to do is exhibit an orthogonal matrix that saturates its upper bound.

Comment: if you don't know von Neumann trace you can do this with polar decomposition, basically mimic this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518238/optimizing-traceqtz-subject-to-qtq-i/